# How to reinstall Joomla 1.5 site on Hostgator without breaking it?

Tags: installation, joomla-1.5, hosting

My website was made in Joomla 1.5 and transferred from previous host.

How would I reinstall Joomla on Hostgator and edit the website without breaking it?

Are there any tips or a tutorial video to help me through this?

Comment: This is going to be problematic on Hostgator servers (probably at other providers too), since Joomla 1.5 is running on PHP 5.3 and the minimum on Hostgator is PHP 7.3  Probably the site should be upgraded first to Joomla 2.5 (then further to 3). Quite a lot of work, first on a Test environment then you could upload that on Hostgator. https://docs.joomla.org/images/cache/4/43/Migrating_from_Joomla_1%252E5_to_Joomla_2%252E5.html

Comment: Hostgator still allow you to use PHP 5.6 on their Windows servers. Personally, I'd deploy it on your local PC, upgrade to 4.x, then deploy back to your hosting provider. Remember that (depending on the sites of your site), it's sometimes quicker to build a new 4.x site than to upgrade from 1.5 to 4.x